# TCPDF: cannot generate PDF file from HTML input

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm working on a simple PHP code which grabs data from employee database and convert itu a nicely PDF-formatted CV (with [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/)). Since doing the layout directly in PHP is quite painful, I think doing the layout in HTML, and feeds it to PHP is easier, shown by [this example](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_006/).

So this is my CV.
[image]

And this is the source:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Resume</title>
</head>

<body>
<img src="umbrella_logo.jpg">

<p align="left">
<b>Armin Hoffman</b>
<br>
UI/UX Designer
</p>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th align="left"><img src="blank_small.jpg">Profile</th>
  <tr>
    <td alignt="left">Etsy doostang zoodles disqus groupon greplin oooj voxy zoodles, weebly ning heekya handango imeem plugg dopplr jibjab, movity jajah plickers sifteo edmodo ifttt zimbra. Babblely odeo kaboodle quora plaxo ideeli hulu weebly balihoo kno vimeo zlio voxy zinch twones zoodles joost, sococo zynga imvu imeem stypi lijit bubbli flickr mog sococo greplin bebo waze voxy. Spotify kno diigo sifteo dropio sococo chegg meevee empressr kosmix groupon handango, cloudera mzinga chartly plickers loopt xobni airbnb prezi.</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>

<img src="blank_small.jpg"><b>Experience</b></img>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Red Design Limited, San Diego, CA 91232</th>
    <th>Professional UI/UX Designer</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>April 2009 - May 2013</td>
    <td rowspan="2"><ul style="font-size:11pt;list-style-type:img|png|2|2|logo_example.png">
    <li>Sold over 100 large interface design with word press, CSS 3 & HTML 5 coding</li>
    <li>Extended design software research and web analysis, design & application</li>
    <li>Designed multitasking web research and multiple print for official uses</li>
    <li>User experience designer along with HTML 5, Word press, SEO, CSS 3, Java</li>
<ul>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Matrix Media Limited, San Diego, CA 41262</th>
    <th>Senior Web Designer</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Feb 2007 - Nov 2009</td>
    <td rowspan="2"><ul style="font-size:11pt;list-style-type:img|png|2|2|logo_example.png">
    <li>Made over 500 large interface design with word press, CSS 3 & HTML 5 coding</li>
    <li>Extended design software research and web analysis, design & application</li>
    <li>Designed multitasking web research and multiple print for official uses</li>
    <li>User experience designer along with HTML 5, Word press, SEO, CSS 3, Java</li>
<ul>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>


</body>
</head>
```

Then combine it with PHP, like this:

```
    <?php

require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 006');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 006', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO); 

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$html = <<<EOF
<img src="umbrella_logo.jpg">

<p align="left">
<b>Armin Hoffman</b>
<br>
UI/UX Designer
</p>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th align="left"><img src="blank_small.jpg">Profile</th>
  <tr>
    <td alignt="left">Etsy doostang zoodles disqus groupon greplin oooj voxy zoodles, weebly ning heekya handango imeem plugg dopplr jibjab, movity jajah plickers sifteo edmodo ifttt zimbra. Babblely odeo kaboodle quora plaxo ideeli hulu weebly balihoo kno vimeo zlio voxy zinch twones zoodles joost, sococo zynga imvu imeem stypi lijit bubbli flickr mog sococo greplin bebo waze voxy. Spotify kno diigo sifteo dropio sococo chegg meevee empressr kosmix groupon handango, cloudera mzinga chartly plickers loopt xobni airbnb prezi.</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>

<img src="blank_small.jpg"><b>Experience</b></img>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Red Design Limited, San Diego, CA 91232</th>
    <th>Professional UI/UX Designer</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>April 2009 - May 2013</td>
    <td rowspan="2"><ul style="font-size:11pt;list-style-type:img|png|2|2|logo_example.png">
    <li>Sold over 100 large interface design with word press, CSS 3 & HTML 5 coding</li>
    <li>Extended design software research and web analysis, design & application</li>
    <li>Designed multitasking web research and multiple print for official uses</li>
    <li>User experience designer along with HTML 5, Word press, SEO, CSS 3, Java</li>
<ul>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
EOF;

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

$pdf->lastPage();

// ---------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('out_cv.pdf', 'I');

?>
```

PHP shows this error message:

> Notice: Undefined index: rows in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\resumebuilder\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 16923
>
> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\resumebuilder\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 16925
>
> Notice: Undefined index: cols in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\resumebuilder\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 16477
>
> Notice: Undefined index: thead in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\resumebuilder\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 16492
>
> Notice: Undefined index: thead in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\resumebuilder\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 16505
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\resumebuilder\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18121
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\resumebuilder\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18188
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\resumebuilder\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18214
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\resumebuilder\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18269
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\resumebuilder\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19508
>
> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
>   implements Countable in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\resumebuilder\tcpdf\tcpdf.php
>   on line 19537
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\resumebuilder\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19540
>
> Notice: Undefined index: old_cell_padding in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\resumebuilder\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19750 TCPDF
>   ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

I guess writeHTML() doesn't have a really capable HTML-parser? How to fix this?

Comment: Echo `$html` variable

Comment: It looks like you are only adding part of the HTML to the `$html` variable. There is no `html` tag, no `head` tag and no `body` tag.

Comment: @Dave. Those `html`, `head`, and `body` tags are not necessary. Remove the `table`-related part from my PHP code, and the PDF will be generated. Of course, only logo, name, and title are rendered.